# PHP Regex Remove Everything After Last Character In String

Tags: php, regex

I have the following string of img url's which I'm trying to sanitize

```
$img_string = http://image.s5a.com/is/image/saks/0401694719016_647x329.jpg," "="">/-/http://image.s5a.com/is/image/saks/0401694719016_A1_647x329.jpg," "="">
```

I'm exploding the string first like this

```
$img_array = explode('/-/',  $img_string);
```

But I can't find a regex to remove everything after the last character in the image url.

e.g. regardless whether the img url ends in .png or .jpg or .jpeg, I need to just sanitize it.
My expected output is

`http://image.s5a.com/is/image/saks/0401694719016_647x329.jpg`

instead of

`http://image.s5a.com/is/image/saks/0401694719016_647x329.jpg," "="">`

So my question is, can someone help me with the required regex to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: http://image.s5a.com/is/image/saks/0401694719016_647x329.jpg instead of http://image.s5a.com/is/image/saks/0401694719016_647x329.jpg," "="">

Comment: substring until the comma.

Comment: Are you missing quotes around the `$img_string` assignment? It's not clear what is in your string and what isn't.

Comment: @Barmar yea, sorry in my actual code it's not like that, this is just an example situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?<=jpg|png|jpeg).*
```

Try this.Replace by `empty string`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/rQ6mK9/44

Comment: So should I use preg_replace with this regex?

Comment: @user2028856 Yes you should.This will replace anything after png jpg or jpeg

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg_match` using this regex:

```
[^,]+
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/rV5wG4/1)

Alternatively you can use this regex as well for `preg_match`:

```
^.+?\.(png|jpe?g)
```

Answer (score 0):

Should work with this, deletes the comma from the URL:

```
if (preg_match_all("/(.*?),/is", $img_string, $matches)) {
  $url = $matches[1][0];
  echo $url;
}
```

**Edit:** tested here: http://ideone.com/pq1WzA

Comment: But the thing is, the stuff after the comma is just a demo, it's not always like that, sometimes there are other characters or symbols after the final jpg or png. So I need something more flexible

Answer (score 0):

removing everything after the first comma like this :

```
$result = preg_replace('@[,].*$@ui', '', $img_string);
```